# How to intercept an IInvocation using dynamic proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

Is it possible to intercept an IInvocation using dynamic proxy and windsor (if windsor is even needed for such a case. I am using it to configure the proxy generation though)?
I would like to log that an interception has changed the call to the intercepted method.
For example the passed arguments were changed or the return value.
Note that this is for debug only purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code below:

```
public class TransactionInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;
    public TransactionInterceptor(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        _UnitOfWork.Begin();

        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            _UnitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _UnitOfWork.RollBack();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, its possible, I recommend to read [this](http://kozmic.pl/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/)

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how and refers to a very very general tutorial. Your answer is very similar to some guy that paste http://msdn.microsoft.com as an answer to a specific C# question. **Read my question again**.